# unable to parse regex pattern form file to the variable in powershell

Tags: regex, powershell, shell, scripting, powershell-2.0

I am looking for whether the folder name is as per the below regex pattern in powershell.

1. Check first 4 letters are HOST.
2. Check next 3 or 4 letters as per the shortnames in the c:\shortnameslist.csv.
3. Check the last three letters are END.

#$shortname = (Import-Csv "c:\shortnameslist.csv")

$foldername = "FOLDERABSNAME"

$regex =  '\b^(HOST)($shortname)(END)\b'

$foldername -match $regex

Problem:

How to parse the middle part "short name" from the csv list in the regex pattern.
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: It seems all you need is to grab all values from the first column into a list/array, and then join with `|` and use `$regex = '^HOST(?:$shortname)END$'`. Note `-match` is case insensitive. Use `-cmatch` for a case sensitive match.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You will need double quotes around the regex, otherwise the variable `$shortname` will not expand

Comment: @Theo Yes, sorry for not noticing while copy/pasting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine the shortname values from the CSV with the regex 'OR' symbol '|'
Escape any possible regex special characters

```
$shortname = (Import-Csv -Path 'c:\shortnameslist.csv' | ForEach-Object { [regex]::Escape($_.shortname) }) -join '|'
$regex = "^HOST($shortname).*END$"

$foldername = 'HOSTIFS-blahblahEND'  # "FOLDERABSNAME"
$foldername -match $regex  # --> True
```

If this returns $true, then the matching shortname can be found in `$matches[1]`

If the comparison needs to be Case-Sensitive, change `-match` into `cmatch`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The solution is working as expected.